# Is it possible to implement licensing in SharePoint hosted add-in

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-hosted-app, licensing

I am working in SharePoint Online, I have added multiple CEWPs with JSOM/ REST to get data from SharePoint lists.
Now I want to create SharePoint Hosted App(using my JSOM/REST code) with License Model.
 Is it possible to implement licensing in Sharepoint Hosted Apps?

I have already seen

- https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/SharePoint-2013-Import-f5f680a6
- https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/officeapps/2012/11/09/licensing-your-apps-for-sharepoint/

but above articles are based on Auto Hosted Apps, which has been depreciated.

Thanks in Advance for any help.